# Поворот объекта в игре

Tags: разработка-игр, математика, логика

Работаю над игрушкой и там есть такая система: существа перемещаются только по оси `x` и `y` (раздельно). Причем есть важное правило, если игрок пошел "вверх", и нажмет "вправо", существо сначала развернется на N градусов, чтобы достигнуть угла -90, а потом пойдет. Если снова нажмет "вверх", существо развернется до 0 градусов.

Имею такю логику вращения:

`--- 0 ---
 90   -90
-- 180 --`

Уже на протяжении нескольких часов сижу с блокнотом и ручкой, вывожу формулу. Видимо, я забыл какую-то очень важную тему...

**Что идет не так и как должно быть?**

**Входные данные:**

- **entity.angle** - текущий угол
- **entity.rotate** - угол **к которому** надо повернуться

**Выходные данные:**

- Делать `-delta` или `+delta` ?

Пример 1. Игрок повернут на градус **0** (смотрит вверх), надо выполнить поворот направо, что приведет к **-90** `(кратчайший способ повернуться против часовой оси)`.

Пример 2. Игрок повернут на градус **180** (смотрит вниз), надо выполнить поворот направо, что приведет к **-90** `(кратчайший способ повернуться по часовой оси)`.

И тд.

В моем случае получается так, что для перехода из 0 в -90 он делает полный круг, и из 180 в -90 полный круг, но так не должно быть...) Язык не важен, но работаю на `JavaScript`.

**Последний вариант, который работает очень косо, но близко:**

```
           if (entity.angle > movement.rotate) {
                entity.angle -= delta;
                if (entity.angle + movement.rotate === 0) {
                    entity.angle = movement.rotate;
                    resetRotation();
                }
            } else if (entity.angle < movement.rotate) {
                entity.angle += delta;
                if (entity.angle - movement.rotate === 0) {
                    entity.angle = movement.rotate;
                    resetRotation();
                }
            } else {
                entity.angle = movement.rotate;
                resetRotation();
            }
```

Comment: что-то непонятно, разве поворот вправо - не всегда _по_ часовой стрелке?

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
t = (rotate - angle + 540) % 360 - 180
if t == -180: # не обязательно
    t = 180
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понятна суть вопроса.
Но, думаю я понял о чем вы.

Могу предложить следующую схему:

1. ввести переменную которая отвечает за вектор направления, например `vectorDirection`.
2. константы отвечающие за само направление: **UP**, **DOWN**, **LEFT**, **RIGHT**, которым будет соответствовать **угол** поворота.
3. по нажатию клавиши клавиатуры менять направление.
4. в `switch` в зависимости от направления двигать героя.

А еще, ввести переменную которая отвечает за то - сделал ли игрок ход после смены направления или нет, и разрешать менять направление только после хода.